# Corporate Finance ok?

Tags: discussion

I've seen the tag Corporate-Finance being used, but I've also seen a question closed...

I would like to post a question on the basic principle of Assets=Liabilities + Equity, and how to finance sales growth. Is this ok on this forum?

Answer (score 6):

My standard advice in this situation is that you should post your question and see what happens. Especially during the beta, it is useful to see how a broad range of question types go down and nobody will be annoyed if it turns out your question isn't a great fit.